# Скажите, как показать элемент через DataTemplateSelector в UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

Скажите, пожалуйста, как тут реализовать `DataTemplateSelector` я пытаюсь по нажатию на элемент из `ListView` показать его содержимое и почему-то `Selector` не возвращает нужные мне данные.

**Вот мой класс MyDataTemplateSelector на C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Task2
{
   public class MyDataTempletSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
        public DataTemplate ColorTemplate { get; set;}
        public DataTemplate IconTeamplate {get; set;}
        public DataTemplate GradientTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            ListView listView = new ListView();
            Root root = new Root();
            if (root.Type == TypeEnum.Color)
            {
                return ColorTemplate;
            }
            else if (root.Type == TypeEnum.Gradient)
            {
                return GradientTemplate;
            }
            else if (root.Type == TypeEnum.Pattern)
            {
                return IconTeamplate;
            }
            return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
        }
      
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Task2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Task2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" d:DesignWidth="1538.183" d:DesignHeight="893.986">
    
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:MyDataTempletSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplet">
            <local:MyDataTempletSelector.GradientTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ListView>
                        
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyDataTempletSelector.GradientTemplate>
            <local:MyDataTempletSelector.IconTeamplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Detail" >
                    <ListView>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{x:Bind IconUrl,Mode=OneWay}" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyDataTempletSelector.IconTeamplate>
            
            <local:MyDataTempletSelector.ColorTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Detail" >
                    <ListView>
                        <Border Background="{x:Bind IconList ,Mode=OneWay}" Width="25" Height="25" />
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyDataTempletSelector.ColorTemplate>
        </local:MyDataTempletSelector>
    </Page.Resources>

    <ListBox>
        <ListView  
          ItemsSource = "{x:Bind Tittle }" 
          ItemTemplateSelector = "{StaticResource MyDataTemplet}" ItemClick="MyListView_ItemClick">
        </ListView>

    </ListBox>
</Page>
```

**MainPage**

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public List<Root> Tittle { get; set; } = new List<Root>();
        public Root[] RootObject { get; set; }
        public List<Detail> ColorList { get; set; } = new List<Detail>();
        public List<Detail> IconList { get; set; } = new List<Detail>();
        public List<GradientProps> gradientProps { get; set; } = new List<GradientProps>();
        // ObservableCollection<Root> RootObjToList { get; set;}
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            string FilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Class1.json");
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(FilePath))
            {
                var json = file.ReadToEnd();
                RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root[]>(json);
                foreach (var item in RootObject)
                {
                    Tittle.Add(new Root
                    {
                        Title = item.Title
                    });
                   
                }
                foreach (var items in RootObject)
                {
                    foreach (var item in items.Details)
                    {
                        switch (item.DetailType)
                        {
                            case TypeEnum.Pattern:
                                IconList.Add(new Detail
                                {
                                    IconUrl = item.IconUrl
                                });
                                break;
                            case TypeEnum.Color:
                                ColorList.Add(new Detail
                                {
                                    FillColor = item.FillColor
                                });
                                break;
                            case TypeEnum.Gradient:
                                gradientProps.Add(new GradientProps
                                {
                                    GradientStop1 = item.GradientProps.GradientStop1
                                });
                                break;
                        }
                    }
}
```

Comment: Вы знаете, что 2 аккаунта на SO это не хорошо? И это карается блокировкой/удалением одного из них...

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ ну вот я уже несколько дней пытаюсь решить эту задачу не получаеться , все свое время почти трачу на это если не трудно подскажи как разобраться с этим ?

Comment: Простите, может грубо будет, но я не горю желанием помогать тому, кто нарушает правила сообщества, в котором я нахожусь. Также мне не ясна ваша проблема, а вы, не помогаете ее понять. Я уже спрашивал у одного из ваших аккаунтов, "зачем вам `DataTemplateSelector`", но внятного ответа я так и не получил. Вы сами себе стреляете в ногу с ним, ибо тут достаточно `DataTemplate` с указанием типа и вида, который вам нужен, не более, но нет, вы хотите селектор...

Comment: Насчет правил я согласен с вами учту ваши слова теперь не только не нарушать, но и сам буду следить что бы их не нарушали. а насчет задачи  может я не совсем  ее понимаю   да возможно без DataTemplateSelector можно ее легче решить но так она поставлена что обязательно это использовать, я много читаю в разных статьях смотрел просто.   С  UWP сталкиваюсь первый раз.

Comment: Ну как я говорил, ваша задача решается [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41430530/6808809), без каких либо селекторов, кто у вас там требует его - на кол надо, ибо советует лишнюю ересь (ИМХО). Если брать ваш код, то тут пара замечаний: 1. Привязка идет к `List<Root> Tittle`, а `List<>` не имеет реализации оповещения UI об изменениях, то есть при добавление или удаление туда чего либо, вы не увидите изменения в UI. Решение - используйте `ObservableCollection<>` или `BindingList<>`, они из коробки реализуют `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: 2. Я не вижу у вас `DataContext` (надеюсь установлен) и привязки работают. 3. Я бы `DataTemplate` вынес в отдельные ресурсы и сделал бы так, как показано в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/data-template-selector).